# Is there a way to get Jboss Seam to scan only certain packages for annotated classes?

Tags: optimization, jboss, annotations, seam

Sorry if there is an obvious answer - I'm new to seam and tasked with optimizing an application's startup where it is scanning almost the entire application's classpath for classes annotated with seam annotations.  This takes about 30 seconds.  We found that if we extract all those classes into a separate JAR and place the seam.properties in that JAR instead of in our WEB-INF/classes, the scanning takes about 50% of that time.

While this is an option, it's not our first choice due to resistance to changing the deployed structure of this application.

So... is there any way to feed SEAM a list of packages that might make its scanning a little faster?  Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that there is a simple configuration that you can change so SEAM is not scanning the whole classpath. The scan for jars is faster because if the jar does not contain the properties all the classes inside will not be checked one by one. Because you have a SEAM web app, on startup all classes in web-inf are scanned.

Probably you can overwrite some functions in the Init class which is i think responsible to scan the app. Honestly, I am wondering why you think that scanning is the biggest part in the startup phase. Hibernate takes a good part of startingtime too just mention one example. Our Jboss 4.2 server starts up in about 30 sec total. But we have several jars and no classes directly in web-inf.

Also starting up the server is normally done once each xx month. Are you using jboss AS? You can switch off unneccessary modules for example which gives you more speed or if you do not use Ejbs you can switch to tomcat and half the startup time just like this.

Comment: In the end I ended up customizing jboss-seam (and intend to submit the changes back to the project once we let them bake a little).  The issue for us is that we have an EAR project with multiple WARs that initialize seam.  As each WAR initializes seam, it scans the entire classpath for JARs/folders with the flag files in them (e.g. seam.properties, and when found, then processes that entire JAR/folder.  If that JAR is in the ear/lib folder, you get that process repeated for each WAR that initializes seam.  My change was to use some caching to preclude paying this cost >1x.